# If you do a many to many relationship in a MySQL db is it necessary to transfer all of the key id's to the join table?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, junction-table

So I am working with MySQL workbench 5.2 and i am making an EER diagram for my database, and when I make a many to many relationship between a table (and those tables already have relationships with other tables) it creates a junction table with all of the other relationships in the two tables that you are joining.. my question is: is it necessary to have all of those other keys? can't you just have the primary key of the join table and then just the id's of the two tables you are relating to? Or am I overlooking something?

here is part of my DB:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
  Table `test`.`storys_has_comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`storys_has_comments` (
    `storys_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `storys_user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `comments_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`storys_id`, `storys_user_id`, `comments_id`) ,
    INDEX `fk_storys_has_comments_comments1` (`comments_id` ASC) ,
    INDEX `fk_storys_has_comments_storys1` (`storys_id` ASC, `storys_user_id` ASC) )
 ENGINE = MyISAM;

  -- -----------------------------------------------------
   Table `test`.`storys`
  -- -----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`storys` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL ,
     `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
     `catagories_id` INT NOT NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `user_id`, `catagories_id`) ,
     INDEX `fk_storys_user` (`user_id` ASC) ,
     INDEX `fk_storys_catagories1` (`catagories_id` ASC) )
  ENGINE = MyISAM;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
 Table `test`.`comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`comments` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL ,
   `body` TINYTEXT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

so as you can see in the story table it has foreign keys to multiple things even though it only links to two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should have all of the primary keys of the tables you are linking.

I am not sure that you are choosing your primary keys correctly.  Why use 'user_id' and 'catagories_id' as part of a composite key when you have a unique id story_id?

Are you confusing foreign keys with primary ones?

Comment: I added an example of what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Edited to reflect changes in question

Comment: Thank you for your update. I'm not sure that I follow. are you saying that the storys_has_comments table should change the primary key to be story_id? and as far as your second question I believe i know the difference... here's how I understand it: you can only have one primary key in each table, and that primary key can never have the same twice. a foreign key is just a way to reference the primary key of another table in the data base, but it too has to never repeat.. is this correct?

Comment: From the above I would suggest that your Stories table only needed one primary key story_id.  I think that the other ids you have there are foreign keys and not primary ones.  In this case I think your link table should just consist of story_id and comment_id.

Comment: A foreign key value can repeat in a table, that is it's reason to be.